# Pygame animation centering issue

Tags: python, pygame

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/d7de3ee0dd95e2e996ac855b93771e22)

I'm not sure why my attack animation is lower than the other animations for my enemy. Every time it attacks it's `y` seems lower. I'm not sure why, even though I centered all of them the same.

```
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
player_rect.centerx += 0
player_rect.centery += -6
window.blit(player_image, player_rect)
```

My enemies class:

```
class rat:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.upshot = [pygame.image.load("rawlk (" + str(i) + ").png").convert_alpha() for i in range(1, 12)]
        self.idle = [pygame.image.load("idle (" + str(i) + ").png").convert_alpha() for i in range(1, 21)]
        self.id = [pygame.image.load("id (" + str(i) + ").png").convert_alpha() for i in range(1, 21)]
        self.move2 = [pygame.image.load("walk (" + str(i) + ").png").convert_alpha() for i in range(1, 12)]

        self.att = [pygame.image.load("att (" + str(i) + ").png").convert_alpha() for i in range(1, 8)]
        self.at = [pygame.image.load("at (" + str(i) + ").png").convert_alpha() for i in range(1, 8)]
        
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.fps = 60
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.time = 0
        self.direction = "move"
        self.direction = "move2"

        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "att"
        self.direction = "at"
        self.direction = "id"

        self.speed = 1
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ratso.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load("ratso2.png").convert_alpha() 
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("Gugi-Regular.ttf", 20)
        self.scoretext = self.font.render("Lv 1", True, (255,255,255))
        self.scorerect = self.scoretext.get_rect()
        self.scorerect.center = ((400,550))

        self.hitbox2 = (self.x - 47, self.y + 11, 169, 52) # NEW
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 129, 52) # NEW
        
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
         



    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "move":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.upshot

        elif self.direction == "idle":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.idle

        elif self.direction == "id":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.id

        elif self.direction == "move2":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.move2


        elif self.direction == "att":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.att

        elif self.direction == "at":
            self.clock.tick(30)
            image_list = self.at
                        
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
            # Time until the next game
            inter_time_delay = 2500 // self.fps
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
            # Showing next frame
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0
 
        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
            
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]



        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y + 30, 46,60)

        # --------------------------------------------------------------------- center all of them
        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 0
        player_rect.centery += -6
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)

     # --------------------------------------------------------------------- center all of them

        window.blit(self.scoretext,(self.x + 15,self.y - 50))
        self.hitbox2 = (self.x - 190, self.y - 22, 159, 40) # NEW
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 80, self.y - 22, 159, 40) # NEW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all frames used for animation appear to be the same height. To compensate for this, and since the rat is on the floor, you need to define the bottom of the rectangle (`midbottom`), not the center:

<s>`player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)`</s>

```py
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(midbottom = self.get_rect().midbottom)
window.blit(player_image, player_rect)
```

Note, If the animation frames are of different sizes or if the rat's position on the sprite changes, the rat's position in the game will also change during the animation.

Comment: not sure why not its causing my other [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/5714e3ae2986e60062092c26abb65baf) move animation to be higher now

Comment: @HabibIsmail Is there a transparent border at the bottom of the images?  Is the size of `self.get_rect()` different to the size of the images? You have to solve problems like yourself. We cannot see your sprites. If the images are a different size or the rat's position on the sprite is different, the rat's position in the game will also be different.

Comment: ok I see the problem my walking sprites  are 190 by 66 and my attack is 190 by 88